# on draw on an android button

Tags: android, text, draw

First I'm new to android. 
Okay, here goes.
I'm attempting to override the onDraw of a button, because I want to create a different styled button.. Something ever so slightly different. 
Now I can draw the background quite easily, but I can't for the life of me figure out why I have no text on my button.

```
public class TriButton extends Button {

private Paint m_paint = new Paint();
private int m_color = 0XFF92C84D; //LIKE AN OLIVE GREEN.. 
public TriButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}
public void onDraw(Canvas iCanvas) {
    //draw the button background
    m_paint.setColor(m_color);      
    iCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight()), 30, 30, m_paint);
    //draw the text
    m_paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    iCanvas.drawText( "bash is king", 0, 0, m_paint);
}
public static RelativeLayout.LayoutParams GetRelativeParam(int iLeft, int iTop, int iWidth, int iHeight){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iHeight, iWidth);
    params.leftMargin = iLeft;
    params.topMargin = iTop;
    return params;
}
}
```

Here's the code that creates the button.

```
 RelativeLayout  relLay = new RelativeLayout(this);

    m_button = new TriButton(this);
    setContentView(relLay);

    relLay.addView(m_button, m_button.GetRelativeParam(0,0,100,500) );
```

Now everything I've read has me expecting to see text in my olive green button oval button. 
The olive green oval shows up, but it doesn't have text in it.. It is a void. A green smudge that laughs at me and reminds me with it's silence, that I am utterly alone :(.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suppose that Button.onDraw() method contains logic about drawing Text on Button. I suggest you to 1) set button's background as transparent, 2) put super.onDraw(iCanvas) at the last of your own onDraw()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured, it's not visible because coordinates are (0,0) which is bottom left of the button, so text is not visible. Try this and it works:

```
iCanvas.drawText( "bash is king", 0, 15, m_paint);
```

Olive green is a good choice btw :)

Comment: I adjusted the button to fill the whole screen, and tried the above code.. It showed the text.. Thanks..
I did confirm that 0,0 is the top left, not the bottom... That said, I think the 0,0 refers to the bottom left corner of the text. How strange is this combo.

Comment: Yep.. 0,0 refers to the top left of the button.. so it puts the bottom left of the text at the top left of the button.  And thus my text is drawn off the top of the button.. (0, textHeight) will draw the text at the left,top of the button.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would do that via xml.

for examle put the following in the layout of your custom class:

```
android:background="@drawable/shape"
```

and then something like that which would be shape.xml placed in /drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
    android:width="2px"
    android:color="#555555"/>
    <corners
    android:radius="10px"/>
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

This example creates a rounded rectangle with a border and a gradient in it. Let me know if you need further explanation.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I'm currently using a rounded rect as a sample.. Also I'm creating buttons through code on purpose.. in my app, I don't know how many buttons I'll need.. so XML is useless..

Comment: Had to vote down the response, as I was asking about how to do something in code.  But I do appreciate the effort.

Comment: Seriously, you did not ask for a code only way. Besides that a code only approach is not the right way as you can create xml based buttons or other stuff at runtime, too.

Comment: ShadowMare.  (kewl nic btw) I am curious about the use of XML. I don't see why.. I've read all the reasons for it's use, but I don't buy them.  It means I have to learn to use Java, and xml at the same time.  Further it means I have to maintain two files to control the the look of one button.  Oh.. and should I want to port my app to objective C.. all the xml work would be for nod.  At least the java could be converted.

Comment: I take your point on my not asking for code.. if you edit your post. (add a space or something) I'll remove my vote, and vote you back up.

Comment: Very kind of you. I suggested XML because it tries to seperate design and content. Although you are right with the issue when you need to port that stuff to objective-c. See the official doc if you are interested: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I'm actually porting a RIM app.. that used to be a palm (before it sucked) app.  And also lives as a PPC app. It has a very specific look to it, and we want to keep it as much the same as we can.

Answer (score 0):

To draw text in your button, get rid of the call to drawText() within the onDraw of your button class.   All you need to do is call setText on the instance of the button since Button extends view:

```
m_button.setText("bash is king");
```

Also, to make a custom button, you may want to consider just using an Image and assigning an OnClickListener to it.